# How to do a success callback when loading JS includes from another script file

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, include, dynamic-loading

I have legacy web app situation where I can't load ***jquery.min.js*** from a script tag in the HTML markup..  so I have to load it with some js in another existing script file

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
head.appendChild(script);
```

The problem is..  when the include load is slow.. there are jQuery functions
(also dynamically loaded on the page) that try to run and can't find jQuery

Is there some cross-browser way to do a callback in the above code that calls the jQuery ready function after the jquery.min.js include file finishes downloading from the CDN?     Thanks,

**EDIT:**

Using Mike's code this is working with **onload** for nearly all browsers except
IE 8 or earlier.. and other browsers which need **onreadystatechange** I guess

**JSFIDDLE HERE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/BmyGC/

Comment: http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html

Answer (score 3):

try

```
if(script.onreadystatechange)
  script.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
      if(script.readyState == "complete"  || script.readyState=="loaded")
   {
   script.onreadystatechange = false;
       console.log("complete");
   }
  }
 else
 {
    script.onload = function()
    {
        console.log("complete");
    }
 }
```

Comment: this would be great but I thought this function was not fully cross browser or maybe I'm reading this wrong..  

http://content.screencast.com/users/ssking44/folders/Snagit/media/b5e515a3-17bb-44b2-a8e1-369d52c9609b/12.09.2011-00.50.09.png

Comment: if onreadystatechange not supported, then performed "onload" event

Comment: I got the onload branch to work but not the readyState part.. 
even tried this with latest IE..          


`s = document.createElement("script");  

s.src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js";  

if(s.addEventListener) {  
 s.addEventListener("load",callback,false);  

}else if(s.readyState) {  
 s.onreadystatechange = callback;  

}  
document.body.appendChild(s);  

function callback() {   

     //load the jQuery code  

}`  

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180173(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: with onload.. this is works well in all but older IE.. I have created a jsfiddle to debug the onreadystate version..  [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/BmyGC/) .. nearly there!  thanks

Comment: It worked like a charm. Can you please help me understand the logic behind it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would put my jquery-based code in yet another separate javascript file, and load that file in exactly the same way you are loading the jquery.min.js.  Just do so immediately after jquery.min.js.  That should work.

*edit*

Okay, since that isn't working, try this:

```
function jqChecker()
{
  if (! jQuery )
  {
    setTimeout(jqChecker, 500); // adjust as needed.
  }
  else
  {
   // insert code to dynamically load your external js file here
  }
}
jqChecker();
```

Comment: I'm looking at this now in Chrome dev tool timeline and the second (jQ dependent) file seems to load before the jQuery.min.js finishes..  even though the second one starts later..  second one wins race. hence need to start it when a callback fires I'm thinking..

Comment: I don't think there really is a way to get a real callback when the external files are loaded - but, I've demoed a ghetto means of doing the same, above.

Comment: interesting  .. I thought about a timer.. but seemed too inelegant.  I will try it now since in this app, the second include file can be quite lazy..